# Django: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host When using urllib2 and httplib2

Tags: python, django, scrape

```
def scrape(request):
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    conn = httplib2.Http()
    resp, content = conn.request(uri=url)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(content)

def scrape1(request):
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Magic Browser' })
    con = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

When I use either of these functions using this url, http://gizmodo.com/5980796/first%20ever-incredible-footage-of-a-thought-being-formed, I get the following error message:

[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This happens when I run this function in a view within my Django app. However, if I run these series of commands in a python shell, I do not get an error and the url is retrieved successfully. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it so I don't get this error anymore. Thank you.